# Hiding access restricted tiles on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have a sharepoint page with multiple tiles on it. Some of the tiles are access restricted to some users. If restricted user looks at the page they see an "access denied" or an "Error" message on page instead of tiles. Is there a way to remove this message and make them see a bank space instead of these "access denied" messages? These are circled in below image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKYhH.png)

Alternatively is there any way i can access restrict tiles so restricted user sees a blank screen instead of tiles or any error message?

Thanks in advance.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer !! I had to click the entire web-part containing the tiles in Page edit mode and in web part properties - advanced tab , update target Audience with relevant user ids.
and sharepoint site hides the entire tile set from a restricted access user.